# Is there a way to put a text based game in a jframe window

Tags: java, jframe

I'm creating an app that should teach people basic math facts, I'm

I've tried importing these libraries:

```
enter code here
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
```

This is the main class of the game witch links to other classes which are just average text based games just with numbers

class mainGame extends JFrame{

```
static JTextField textfield1, textfield2, textfield3;

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner playerInt = new Scanner(System.in); 

   JFrame frame = new JFrame("math game");
   frame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
   frame.pack();
   frame.setSize(300,300);
   frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   textfield1 = new JTextField("Text field 1",10);



System.out.println("What kind of math would you like to practice? 1. addition, 2. subtraction, 3. multiplication, 4. division");
int p = playerInt.nextInt();

if(p == 1){
  // link to addition
  addition.main(args);
}
else if(p == 2){
  // link to subtraction
  subtraction.main(args);
}
else if(p == 3){
  // link to multiplication
  multiplication.main(args);
}
else if(p == 4){
  // link to division
  division.main(args);
}
```

}
}

The results that i would like are the text based game inside the jframe window so that the player plays the game in the window entirely, Instead i get the text based game in the eclipse consul and a yellow window off to the side.

Comment: You seem to output to the console and not using `textfield1` at all: `System.out.println("What kind of math would you like to practice? 1. addition, 2. subtraction, 3. multiplication, 4. division");`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you mean like switching System.out.println with textfield1.out.println?

Comment: You are not actually adding `textfield1` to the frame. You should do `frame.add(textfield1)`

Comment: thanks so much again

Comment: Why do you call frame.pack() and then immediately tell the frame to ignore that and set its size specifically? Also, you should not be creating and manipulating GUI items on the main thread. You need to do that on the EventDispatchThred.